# Copy and Paste formulated column values into a section of a formula in column

Tags: vba

I need to copy the values in column F into the formulas in column E, but specifically into the sum formula, as the required cell references are in F.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TaNrWyAD6PWR50dZ-sUutroTxWDgcl-W
(if the cause is also the delimiter it can be changed to "+" instead of "," .

I used the column F cell as a reference that did work, also tried changing the format of the cell value inside the formula but doesn't workI tried to enter the array into the sum formula but returns error.

I am trying now to iteratively add these into the formula by macro, I know the formula is inefficient I just need it to work as it is the closed this I have for it to work

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rChange As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler 'copy and paste values from column 
    Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("E:E"))
    If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In rChange
            If rCell > "" Then
                With rCell.Offset(0, 7)
                    .Copy.Offset(0, 1).Value.FormulaR1C1 = _
                               "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",RC[-2]-SUM(RC[3],RC[5],RC[7],RC[9]))"
                End With
            Else
                rCell.Offset(0, 0).Clear
            End If
        Next
    End If

ExitHandler:
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rChange = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a Complex Macro. You can write a simple function to acheive this.

[image]

**Function:**

```
Function spl(rng As Range) As Double

Dim a() As String

a = Split(rng.Value, ",")
spl = 0
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    spl = spl + ActiveSheet.Range(a(i))
Next

End Function
```

Comment: is there a chance that this won't work on Mac ? because I have tried multiple changes to the formula keeps giving me a '#NAME?' in the cell I don't think it

Comment: @sammyT ...Honestly I am not sure about Mac. It should work. But I ll let someone else be the Judge of that.